# Reading line in a file that has been purposely changed

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, file, search

So let's say I have something like;

```
def scramble():
    word = open("wordlist.txt", "a")
    userword = input("Give me a word to scramble")
    newword = userword.replace("a", "*")
    newword2 = neword.replace("o", "0")
    word.write(userword)
    word.write(\n)
    word.close
```

Take a word, replace characters with those in the code and append that to a file. How can I then create a different function where I ask the user to enter that word again, the code goes back to that file, almost "decrypts" the word and spits it back out at the user in the most simplest of terms. I don't care how messy I'm just completely lost.

I've attempted to reverse the scrambled word but every time I go to check the file for it, regardless of whether or not the word is in there it fails the check.

```
def unscramble():
    word = open("wordlist.txt", "r")
    userinput = input("Enter a word and I'll see if i have it")
    userinput2 = userinput.replace("*","a")
    userinput3 = userinput2.replace("0","o")
    for line in word:
        if userinput3 in line:
            print("Yes, I do have that word. Would you like to see it scrambled?")
        else:
            print("Sorry, I don't have that")
```

Comment: Try adding the `strip` command, as in `userinput = input("Enter a word and I'll see if i have it").strip()`

Comment: Also, the last two lines of your scramble method should be `word.write('\n')` (with the quotation marks) and `word.close()` with the parentheses; see if those changes make a difference.

Comment: If the user is supposed to enter the **same word** the second time, why are you trying to *decrypt* it? Your file only contains *encrypted* words, so if you want to look up the same word again, you must encrypt the input again. To get a list of encrypted words, you can simply do `words = word.read().split()`. Then you can do `if userinput3 in words: ...`.

Comment: So when having them separated ( this is only a slice of 2 functions )  and alone they work but when I add them to my complete code I get; ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.